# Encryption/Decryption over the HTTPS Network

Tags: java, android, ios, encryption, https

In our app, we are communication with the back-end over the HTTPS network. My confusion is, is there any benefit of using encryption over that.

EDIT: By using encryption, I want to use AES encryption to send request over the network that is already secure. So I was confused if it is extravagant to use AES encryption over already secure connection.

Comment: Yes, the benefit is that your communication will be encrypted. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Do you mean encrypting the data in your applications in addition to using HTTPS?

Answer (score 4):

It's overkill. An SSL connection is all you need if you properly configure your server and know how to manage certificates. Adding another layer of encryption (you didn't describe it, so I assume it's another SSL clone) certainly can't harm, but you have to carefully design and implement it.

The reason why it's not common is because you need to implement your protocol both on the client and on the server, which is not a little effort. And supposedly if you can't keep SSL secure, you shouldn't implement a proprietary protocol altogether.

Also, note that the custom protocol only makes sense if you deploy your **native** client (you tagged "iOS", so I mean a native C/Objective-C implementation) **before** the connection: it's useless to have a Javascript client (you also mentioned HTTP so I guess it's a standard www application) transmitted, because if the attacker can break SSL, it can certainly manipulate the Javascript and at this point your protocol is no secure anymore.

Answer (score 2):

It looks a bit excessive, but I would not say outright no.

Depending on your application, your security concerns and the environments you're working in, this extra "layer" of security, to have your data encrypted before transmitting, might pay off. Maybe the receiving end should not be able to see the data and reroute them somewhere else, maybe because its untrustworthy (3rd party application), maybe simple data privacy reasons (legal).

I do not know wether or not AES is a good solution, I would go for RSA.. but thats another story.